# invalid ObjC Object error in Xcode while debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

As in screenshot, the debugger has last two object named `[0]`
which is my two NSString *variables..

[image]

Both variable can not be assigned.. (i have initialised both..)

```
inquiryId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictObj objectForKey:@"inquiry_id"]];
```

I am assigning from dictionary but it stays `[0]`

when i print the variable in log then it display as shown in image

I dont know which type of error is this..!!

Comment: the reason the it is deallocated

Comment: how whould i recover it?

Comment: What is `dictObj` as it's not shown in the debugger output (neither is `inquiryId` for that matter)?  How is it being populated?

Comment: can you NSLog the dictObj? add it in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution on this issue.!!!

I just `Remove reference` of `My Viewcontroller` & add it again...

That problem was related to something linking issue.!!

It works now..!!

Answer (score 1):

may be because you are assigning object to NSString, try below code:

```
inquiryId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictObj valueForKey:@"inquiry_id"]];
```